# Visual Studio Code compile on save

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

How can I configure Visual Studio Code to compile typescript files on save?

I see it is possible to configure a task to build the file in focus using the `${file}` as an argument.  But I would like this to be done when a file is saved.

Comment: Above link is for VS, not for VS code. Compile on save is different feature than compiling and tasks. It emits only single JS file when saving. I want this to VS code too.

Comment: That is a good suggestion. I opened an internal work item to implement that feature.

Comment: Here is the work item: http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/293070-visual-studio-code/suggestions/7776651-typescript-compile-on-save

Comment: Could you please mark an answer

Comment: Type `tsc <filename> --watch` in the terminal

Comment: Hi, my only one component file is not compiling after save it

Answer (score 252):

#### May 2018 update:

As of May 2018 you no longer need to create `tsconfig.json` manually or configure task runner.

1. Run `tsc --init` in your project folder to create `tsconfig.json` file (if you don't have one already).
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+B</kbd> to open a list of tasks in VS Code and select `tsc: watch - tsconfig.json`.
3. Done! Your project is recompiled on every file save.

You can have several `tsconfig.json` files in your workspace and run multiple compilations at once if you want (e.g. frontend and backend separately).

#### Original answer:

You can do this with Build commands:

Create a simple [`tsconfig.json`](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/tsconfig.json) with `"watch": true` (this will instruct compiler to watch all compiled files):

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "out": "js/script.js",
        "watch": true
    }
}
```

Note that `files` array is omitted, by default all `*.ts` files in all subdirectories will be compiled. You can provide any other parameters or change `target`/`out`, just make sure that `watch` is set to `true`.

Configure your task (<kbd>Ctrl+Shift+P</kbd> -> `Configure Task Runner`):

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "tsc",
    "showOutput": "silent",
    "isShellCommand": true,
    "problemMatcher": "$tsc"
}
```

Now press <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+B</kbd> to build the project. You will see compiler output in the output window (<kbd>Ctrl+Shift+U</kbd>).

The compiler will compile files automatically when saved. To stop the compilation, press <kbd>Ctrl+P</kbd> -> `> Tasks: Terminate Running Task`

I've created a project template specifically for this answer: [`typescript-node-basic`](https://github.com/zlumer/typescript-node-basic)

Comment: Problem with this is it keeps a task running, VS Code knows when I save a less file, or ts file, it feels like redundant to have another watcher just because we can't hook to "On save" command easily. I wonder if someone's already done a extension to run something when specific filetype is saved, would be much better.

Comment: @Ciantic this answer was written before VS Code had extensions support. There's just an [extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items/emeraldwalk.RunOnSave) you're talking about, but it's actually faster to have TypeScript compiler watch files and re-compile only the changed ones.

Comment: What is the difference between the task runner and the basic tsconfig.json ?  Do you need both? tsconfig.json also includes an option "compileOnSave": true

Comment: @Kokodoko bc compileOnSave only works in VS 2015, not Code

Comment: @scape It works in VS Code as well, if you add "-w" to the command line arguments in tasks.json !

Comment: **Actually VSCode does the configuration stuff for you:**
On `configure task`: VSCode will auto-detect that there is a `tsconfig.json` and prompt a dialog where you can choose either `tsc: build - tsconfig.json` or `tsc: watch - tsconfig.json`. 

Choose the latter and VSCode generates the `tasks.json` file (if there was no before) and adds the right configuration for you.

Comment: In Addition to my comment above: The property `"watch": true` is not needed in the `tsconfig.json` file, due to the watch task.

Comment: @zlumer My anwser https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29996145/visual-studio-code-compile-on-save/60374212#60374212 not require pressing Ctrl+Shift+B so is more user friendly.

Comment: So as of today, it is still recommended to use the built in `tsc watch` command instead of the extension because of speed?

Answer (score 43):

If you want to avoid having to use `CTRL`+`SHIFT`+`B` and instead want this to occur any time you save a file, you can bind the command to the same short-cut as the save action:

```
[
    {
        "key": "ctrl+s",          
        "command": "workbench.action.tasks.build" 
    }
]
```

This goes in your keybindings.json - (head to this using File -> Preferences -> Keyboard Shortcuts).

Comment: This should just be an add-on to the above answer (edited). This made my day!

Comment: good answer... ?how to filter whats will be launched... for example: I only want to execute command if the file has html extension ???

Comment: @ZEE yes, this is possible, please see this bit of documentation for [keybindings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_when-clause-contexts) and also [httpete's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34094418/4565795) for a brief example. Specifically, the `when` condition` using `editorLangId` is of import.

Comment: Wont this will override the original command ?

Answer (score 31):

If pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> seems like a lot of effort, you can switch on "Auto Save" (File > Auto Save) and use NodeJS to watch all the files in your project, and run TSC automatically.

Open a Node.JS command prompt, change directory to your project root folder and type the following;

```
tsc -w
```

And hey presto, each time VS Code auto saves the file, TSC will recompile it.

This technique is mentioned in a blog post;

http://www.typescriptguy.com/getting-started/angularjs-typescript/

Scroll down to "Compile on save"

Answer (score 8):

**Write an Extension**

Now that vscode is extensible, it is possible to hook into the on save event via an extension. A good overview of writing extensions for VSCode can be found here:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensions/overview

Here's a simple example that just calls `echo $filepath` and outputs stdout in a message dialogue:

```
import * as vscode from 'vscode';
import {exec} from 'child_process';

export function activate(context: vscode.ExtensionContext) {

    vscode.window.showInformationMessage('Run command on save enabled.');

    var cmd = vscode.commands.registerCommand('extension.executeOnSave', () => {

        var onSave = vscode.workspace.onDidSaveTextDocument((e: vscode.TextDocument) => {

            // execute some child process on save
            var child = exec('echo ' + e.fileName);
            child.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
                vscode.window.showInformationMessage(data);
            });
        });
        context.subscriptions.push(onSave);
    });

    context.subscriptions.push(cmd);
}
```

(Also referenced on this SO question:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/33843805/20489)

**Existing VSCode Extension**

If you want to just install an existing extension, here is one that I wrote available in the VSCode gallery:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items/emeraldwalk.RunOnSave

Source code is available here:
https://github.com/emeraldwalk/vscode-runonsave/blob/master/src/extension.ts

Comment: That existing extension is exactly what I expected, I'm not exaggerating. An extra upvote.

Answer (score 8):

An extremely simple way to auto-compile upon save is to type one of the following into the terminal:

```
tsc main --watch // autosave `main.ts`
tsc -w // autosave all typescript files in your project
```

Note, this will only run as long as this terminal is open, but it's a very simple solution that can be run while you're editing a program.

Comment: `tsc -w` also works for all typescript files in the project

Comment: Worked for me, thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I have struggled mightily to get the behavior I want. This is the easiest and best way to get TypeScript files to compile on save, to the configuration I want, only THIS file (the saved file). It's a tasks.json and a keybindings.json.
[image]

[image]

Comment: for lazy developers:
`{
 "version": "0.1.0",
 "command": "tsc",
 "isShellCommand": true,
 "args": ["--module","amd","--target","ES5","${file}"],
 "showOutput": "silent", 
 "problemMatcher": "$tsc"
} `

keybingings:
`{
        "key": "cmd+s",
        "command": "workbench.action.tasks.build",
        "when":"editorTextFocus && editorLangId == 'typescript'"
}`

Comment: I can say with the latest version of TypeScript 1.8.X and 1.0 of Visual Studio code, the technique I showed is obsolete. 

Simply use a tsconfig.json at the root level of your project and all works automatically for syntax checking.  Then use tsc -w on the command line for watching / recompiling automatically.

{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "amd",
        "target": "ES5",
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "removeComments": true,
        "preserveConstEnums": true,
        "inlineSourceMap": true
    },

    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ]
}

Answer (score 5):

Instead of building a single file and bind Ctrl+S to trigger that build I would recommend to start tsc in watch mode using the following tasks.json file:

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "tsc",
    "isShellCommand": true,
    "args": ["-w", "-p", "."],
    "showOutput": "silent",
    "isWatching": true,
    "problemMatcher": "$tsc-watch"
}
```

This will once build the whole project and then rebuild the files that get saved independent of how they get saved (Ctrl+S, auto save, ...)

Comment: some of these props are deprecated.

Answer (score 4):

In your `tsconfig.json`

```
"compileOnSave": true, // change it to true and save the application
```

also restart your application --> `ng serve`

if the problem is still there then restart your IDE / developer tool

Comment: Does VS code nowadays support that feature? Last time when I checked, it could not save and I needed to use extension to do it.

Comment: Now it does support

Comment: Isn't this only optional for frameworks like angular or react? In a scratched project relying on global tsc I am not sure this will work. My VSCode does not take care of this.

Comment: Nope it doesn't work, I tried your Step 3 to break my file and save it but changes in the terminal are ***not*** happening when saving the (broken) file. By the mere fact that I had to manually add your line of code inside `tsconfig.json` and it *wasn't commented out which I can remove comments and use it* is a say-so that it wouldn't work, and it doesn't.

Comment: It would be nice if it was as simple as compileOnSave. I'm testing with a dirt-simple TS folder project, completely restarted VSCode, absolutely no effect from this directive. Bug?

Answer (score 3):

I implemented compile on save with gulp task using [gulp-typescript](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-typescript) and incremental build. This allows to control compilation whatever you want. Notice my variable tsServerProject, in my real project I also have tsClientProject because I want to compile my client code with no module specified. As I know you can't do it with vs code.

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    ts = require('gulp-typescript'),
    sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');

var tsServerProject = ts.createProject({
   declarationFiles: false,
   noExternalResolve: false,
   module: 'commonjs',
   target: 'ES5'
});

var srcServer = 'src/server/**/*.ts'

gulp.task('watch-server', ['compile-server'], watchServer);
gulp.task('compile-server', compileServer);

function watchServer(params) {
   gulp.watch(srcServer, ['compile-server']);
}

function compileServer(params) {
   var tsResult = gulp.src(srcServer)
      .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
      .pipe(ts(tsServerProject));

   return tsResult.js
      .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./source-maps'))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('src/server/'));

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Current status of this issue:

https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/7015

Answer (score 3):

I use automatic tasks run on folder (should work VSCode >=1.30) in .vscode/tasks.json

```
{
 "version": "2.0.0",
 "tasks": [
    {
        "type": "typescript",
        "tsconfig": "tsconfig.json",
        "option": "watch",
        "presentation": {
            "echo": true,
            "reveal": "silent",
            "focus": false,
            "panel": "shared"
        },
        "isBackground": true,
        "runOptions": {"runOn": "folderOpen"},
        "problemMatcher": [
            "$tsc-watch"
        ],
        "group": {
            "kind": "build",
            "isDefault": true
        }
    }
 ]
}
```

If this still not work on project folder open try Ctrl+shift+P and Tasks: Manage Automatic Tasks in Folder and choose "Allow Automatic Tasks in folder" on main project folder or running folder.

Answer (score 2):

There are various valid answers here but not necessarily good for everyone per different TS compiler env. Maybe following can work globally.

#### Step 1

have a minimum `tsconfig.json` underneath your project root folder, for example,

```
"compilerOptions": {
      "baseUrl": "./",
      "outDir": "./dist/",
      "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
      "sourceMap": true,
      "strict": true,
      "target": "es2017",
      "module": "es2020",
}
# where you can set your outDir accordingly.
```

#### Step 2

set your current TS complier `tsc` to watch the project root folder. To achieve this, open another terminal tab, and run following command and leave it in the background.

```
$ tsc --watch --project ./
# tsc is your working compiler, may be different than this. I currently using global TyperScript Compiler to watch on save therefore tcs. Change to yours accordingly
# ref: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html
```

This is more neat than rely on IDE task watcher.

When you don't need it to watch anymore, simple Ctrl/Command + C to terminate it or even close/recycle the terminal

Answer (score 1):

Select **Preferences -> Workspace Settings** and add the following code, If you have Hot reload enabled, then the changes reflect immediately in the browser

```
{
    "files.exclude": {
        "**/.git": true,
        "**/.DS_Store": true,
        "**/*.js.map": true,
        "**/*.js": {"when": "$(basename).ts"}
    },
    "files.autoSave": "afterDelay",
    "files.autoSaveDelay": 1000
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I can say with the latest version of TypeScript 1.8.X and 1.0 of Visual Studio code, the technique I showed is obsolete. Simply use a tsconfig.json at the root level of your project and all works automatically for syntax checking.
 Then use tsc -w on the command line for watching / recompiling automatically. It will read the same tsconfig.json file for options and config of ts compile.

```
// tsconfig.json

{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "amd",
        "target": "ES5",
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "removeComments": true,
        "preserveConstEnums": true,
        "inlineSourceMap": true
    },
    "exclude": [ "node_modules" ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to increase the watches limit to fix the recompile issue on save, Open terminal and enter these two commands:

```
sudo sysctl fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288
sudo sysctl -p --system
```

To make the changes persistent even after restart, run this command also:

```
echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 | sudo tee /etc/sysctl.d/40-max-user-watches.conf && sudo sysctl --system
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Run tsc --init in your project folder to create tsconfig. json file (if you don't have one already)
2. Press Ctrl+Shift+B to open a list of tasks in VS Code and select "tsc: watch - tsconfig.json"
3. Done! Your project is recompiled on every file save.

This worked for me but for step 2 I can only select "tsc: espion - tsconfig.json" in the list of tasks (no "tsc: watch - tsconfig.json" found in the list)

Answer (score 1):

```
tsc --watch
```

and boom your typescript will compile if your has save your file

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

tried the above methods but mine stopped auto-compile when it felt like it, due to **maximum files to watch** have passed the limit.

run `cat /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches` command .

if it's showing fewer files count including node_modules then open the file 
`/etc/sysctl.conf` in root privilege  and append

`fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288` into the file and save

run again  the  cat command to  see the result. It will work! hopefully!

Comment: I remember seeing this problem a couple years ago with huge projects and there was a similar solution for Windows. Does anyone have that? I think it applied to PHP as well as TS/JS and other languages. If required I'll see if I can dig it up.