# Auto-Build TypeScript Project in Visual Studios Code 2015

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, typescript

I am just starting out in Type Script, and am using the new Visual Studios Code IDE. I am currently facing an issue where I can either use the visual studios type script plug-in, and run the javascript files using node. However it won't build the js file automatically when the ts file is saved. So i uninstalled the plugin, and installed typescript according to this video:

https://egghead.io/lessons/typescript-typescript-up-and-running-in-seconds

Now I can have one ts file be built by using the --watch option, but how would I accomplish auto building multiple .ts files when I move on to more complex projects that will require it?

Also is this the best way to write TypeScript using Visual Studios Code as my IDE? Currently I'm not a huge fan of this set up because I have to have a terminal open to watch a single ts file (which can mean a bunch of windows are required to watch each file, and also a terminal open to run the program.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure whether you use [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) or [Visual Studio 2013](https://www.visualstudio.com/). I assume it's VS Code (if it's not, consider switching. VS Code is really good!).

Now I'll quote myself from [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30319507/2580784).

You can do this with Build commands:

Create a simple [`tsconfig.json`](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/tsconfig.json) with `watch = true` (this will instruct compiler to watch all compiled files):

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES5",
        "out": "js/script.js",
        "watch": true
    }
}
```

Note that `files` array is omitted, by default all `*.ts` files in all subdirectories will be compiled.

Configure your task (`Ctrl+Shift+P` -> `Configure Task Runner`):

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "tsc",
    "showOutput": "silent",
    "isShellCommand": true,
    "problemMatcher": "$tsc"
}
```

Now press `Ctrl+Shift+B` to build the project. You will see compiler output in the output window (`Ctrl+Shift+O`).

See one of my projects for more info:
[`tsconfig.json`](https://github.com/zlumer/mh-random/blob/gh-pages/tsconfig.json), [`.settings/tasks.json`](https://github.com/zlumer/mh-random/blob/gh-pages/.settings/tasks.json).

Comment: so there is no way to do it automatically?

Comment: After you build it once (`Ctrl+Shift+B`), it will watch and re-compile all files on save automatically. You can always `Terminate running task` or close the project to stop the compiler.

Comment: I get the following error: tsc.js(25345, 17) JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'watchFile'

Comment: Probably you use TypeScript compiler from Visual Studio Tools and not the NPM one (it's possible only on Windows).
Check your compiler: `where tsc`.
If the one used is not in `AppData\Roaming\npm` folder (probably under `Program Files`), you should remove it and install from NPM: `npm install -g typescript`.

Comment: building on @zlumer, you will also need to remove the `Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript` path from your system PATH environment variable, so it uses the one from npm. You can check which one is being used in Powershell: `get-command tsc`