# How to run `go fmt` on save, in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

How to make Visual Studio Code (or Go Programming Language Extension) to run `go fmt` (or other tools/commands) on save? Even auto save?

**Update:**
It is working now perfectly inside VSCode, at this time; just need to add some config files inside *.vscode* directory (I use [these](https://github.com/dc0d/plumber/tree/master/.vscode)).

**Update 2019:**
This question is old. The VSCode Go extension has all you need to develop in Go, now.

**Last Update 2019**
BTW It worth mentioning that right above the package declaration inside your test files appears a *run package tests*. If you click it, you can see your code coverage of your code. The covered and not-covered parts are highlighted in different colors.

**Update 2020**
And now, the Go Extension for VSCode, is under the supervision of Go Team!

[image]

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Now, the feature has been implemented, you can enable format on save:

1. Open Settings (`Ctrl + ,`)
2. Search for `editor.formatOnSave` and set it to `true`

Your Go code will be formatted automatically on `Ctrl + s`

Comment: I think this should even be the default setting if you newly install the Go extension.

Comment: Is there a way to change the formatting options? I have enabled the indent with space option but after the file is saved go fmt converts it back to tabs.

Comment: Remember that if you have a different formatter (like Prettier) already set up in VS, this solution will need a final step: You need to change the "default formatter" in settings to "Go".

Comment: For me this solution worked but I have to do ctrl+s even autosave is enabled.

Comment: I know it's an old question, but for future reference @rd22 the fact that this is not configurable actually solves the problem of "tabs vs spaces": just program with spaces as I do, but when you save it gofmt will convert it to a normalized format that everybody else uses. No need to worry about this anymore. I would just recommend configuring the size of your tabs to match the number of spaces you use for indenting.

Answer (score 4):

Its not possible at the moment but its being worked on https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-go/issues/14

Comment: This is not longer up-to-date.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not familiar with 'go fmt' specifically, but you can create a simple vscode extension to handle on save event and execute any arbitrary command passing the file path as an argument.

Here's a sample that just calls `echo $filepath`:

```
import * as vscode from 'vscode';
import {exec} from 'child_process';

export function activate(context: vscode.ExtensionContext) {

    vscode.window.showInformationMessage('Run command on save enabled.');

    var cmd = vscode.commands.registerCommand('extension.executeOnSave', () => {

        var onSave = vscode.workspace.onDidSaveTextDocument((e: vscode.TextDocument) => {

            // execute some child process on save
            var child = exec('echo ' + e.fileName);
            child.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
                vscode.window.showInformationMessage(data);
            });
        });
        context.subscriptions.push(onSave);
    });

    context.subscriptions.push(cmd);
}
```

And the package file:

```
{
    "name": "Custom onSave",
    "description": "Execute commands on save.",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "publisher": "Emeraldwalk",
    "engines": {
        "vscode": "^0.10.1"
    },
    "categories": [
        "Other"
    ],
    "activationEvents": [
        "onCommand:extension.executeOnSave"
    ],
    "main": "./out/src/extension",
    "contributes": {
        "commands": [{
            "command": "extension.executeOnSave",
            "title": "Execute on Save"
        }]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "vscode:prepublish": "node ./node_modules/vscode/bin/compile",
        "compile": "node ./node_modules/vscode/bin/compile -watch -p ./"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "typescript": "^1.6.2",
        "vscode": "0.10.x"
    }
}
```

The extension is enabled via cmd+shift+p then typing "Execute on Save", but it could be reconfigured to start via another command including "*" which would cause it to load any time VSCode loads.

Once the extension is enabled, the event handler will fire whenever a file is saved (NOTE: this doesn't appear to work when file is first created or on Save as...)

This is just a minor modification of a yo code scaffolded extension as outlined here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensions/example-hello-world

**Update**

Here's a Visual Studio Code extension I wrote for running commands on file save. https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items/emeraldwalk.RunOnSave.

Comment: `gofmt` takes a string (the content of the current file opened in editor) via `stdin` and gives a formatted Go code to us via `stdout` or some errors if any via `stderr`. So basically (best I wish for) I want to feed the changed content to `gofmt` and take the output and if there were no errors, save it to the file. I'll play around this to see what I can do in a meaningful timeframe (otherwise I'll fall back to LiteIDE for now). Thanks;

Answer (score 0):

I was using CTRL+S for saving the file manually (this is habitual for me). However, I had a different binding in VS Code that would start with CTRL+S (e.g. swagger extension has a chord where pressing CTRL+S CTRL+W would generate the swagger annotation). This resulted in VS Code waiting for me to press the second chord (CTRL+W) and as such it ignored the save part altogether. I reconfigured all the keybinding chords which had CTRL+S as the first chord to a different combination. After this, pressing CTRL+S formatted my file with gofmt properly.