# How to run `go fmt` on demand after disabling it on save, in Visual Studio Code

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

Related to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33828470/how-to-run-go-fmt-on-save-in-visual-studio-code) about how to run `go fmt` on save, but for me I have disabled `go fmt` on save because I don't like the way it removes import statements while I am still working on the code.

I would like to run `go fmt` on the file I have open when I want to from VS Code. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: here is answer how to trigger format in vscode by keyboard shortcut https://stackoverflow.com/a/29973358/12301864 Do you have Go extension installed?

Answer (score 0):

you can trigger VS-code to format the current document by pressing:

`shift` + `alt` + `F`

or you open the command palette by `CTRL` + `shift` + `P` and then search for `format Document`

Comment: ah, it's the format document command? that uses gofmt?

Comment: unless you disabled language server explicitly, it will use `gopls` for formatting by default.