# Run npm command on keybinding in Visual Studio Code

Tags: npm, visual-studio-code, key-bindings

I want to bundle js files on save using webpack.

This is best accomplished using webpack watch. But whatever...

In the answers below is the result of my googling, which I hope will be useful to somebody at some point.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29996145/visual-studio-code-compile-on-save

Comment: I think having webpack watch the files is a better way to do it, and easier to set up.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Use npm to run webpack bundling on save in VSC** ... or any other npm command you like, like compiling typescript.

Add a `.vscode/tasks.json` to your project:

> See [tasks.json format documentation](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558) for reference

```js
{
    "command": "npm",
    "isShellCommand": true,
    "showOutput": "never",
    "suppressTaskName": true,
    "tasks": [
        {
            "taskName": "bundle",
            "args": ["run", "bundle"],
            "isBuildCommand": true,
            "showOutput": "never"
        }
    ]
}
```

Edit `keybindings.json` (File>Preferences>Keyboard Shortcuts).

Place your key bindings in this file to overwrite the defaults

```js
[
    {
        "key" : "ctrl+s",
        "command" : "workbench.action.tasks.build"
    }
]
```

The `workbench.action.tasks.build` is a built-in vsc hook. See here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/customization/keybindings#_tasks

The task can also be accessed in VSC via

1. `Ctrl+P`
2. Type `task` + space
3. See your task suggested or continue typing it's name

Answer (score 11):

`keybindings.json`

```json
{
    "key": "ctrl+shift+alt+b",
    "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",
    "args": {
        "text": "npm run test\r"
    },
},
```

Comment: To find keybindings.json. Open command pallete (Usually ctrl + shift + P or cmd + shift + P) then look for "Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)". Make sure it's the one with (JSON).